# Markerclusterer Google Maps Api V3 - Bug: Markers partitially not clustered in Zoom Level 2

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

There seems to be a huge bug in Markerclusterer/Markerclusterplus for API V3: In (mainly) zoom-level 2 not all markers are clustered.

However, the same behaviour occurs in speedtest examples (demos!) of Googles reference pages: Markercluster with API V2 works fine, but with V3 it does not.
I have put all speed test versions together using iframes, so you can compare the different versions very easy:
http://findini.com/apps/map/markertest/?visit=sec.

No idea. Anyone who knows a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Use MarkerClustererPlus from http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

There IS a problem with MarkerClusterer.

In createClusters_, the TopRight lat+long are computed, along with the BottomLeft lat+long.

For Zoom levels 3 and higher, TopRight lat > BottomLeft lat and TopRight long > BottomLeft long. These two conditions are ALWAYS true.

But for Zoom level 2, TopRight long is ALWAYS consistently less than BottomLeft long, and this causes all sorts of problems. Hence panning around seems to fix the problem - because it creates conditions for (TopRight long > BottomLeft long) and that causes clustering to work correctly.

For Zoom level 1, the probability of the error condition is lower than for Zoom 2. Hence it may work sometimes, and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this behavior using `MarkererClusterer` (not sure of the version) and `MarkerClustererPlus v2.0.5` (not realizing there were more recent versions).  Expanding on the answer provided by @Ranjeet, I upgraded to `MarkerClustererPlus v2.0.9` and this seemed to solve the problem. http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/